# Postgresql import with COPY - ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date

Tags: postgresql, import

I am trying to use Postgresql COPY and import a file into a database. The first field is a date field. Still I get an error:

```
Error : ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "﻿2014-01-24"
CONTEXT:  COPY test_darwin, line 1, column datelastmodified: "﻿2014-01-24"
```

The field seems to me a perfect date. And even if I copy the date from another record into the import file.

Here is my code:

```
COPY test_table (datelastmodified,institutioncode ,collectioncode, catalognumber, scientificname) FROM '/Users/asle/Desktop/import_test'
```

and my import file (tab-separated):

```
2014-01-24  Fokus   Fokus   333401  Merodon equestris
2014-02-03  Fokus   Fokus   346618  Thanatophilus rugosus
2014-01-24  Test Group  MFU 189028  Potentilla argentea
2014-01-18  Fokus   MFU 342969  Erigeron borealis
2014-01-18  Fokus   Fokus   352801  Galium palustre
2014-01-24  Fokus   Fokus   158921  Cassida rubiginosa
2014-01-18  Fokus   Fokus   353450  Equisetum pratense
2014-01-18  Fokus   MFU 343084  Draba norvegica
2014-01-18  Fokus   MFU 296983  Trifolium medium
2014-01-18  Fokus   Fokus   296983  Bryum rubens
2014-01-24  Fokus   Fokus   355254  Fragaria vesca
2014-02-03  Fokus   Fokus   341767  Bombus ruderarius
2014-01-24  Test Group  MFU 188806  Luzula multiflora multiflora
2014-01-18  Fokus   MFU 351029  Solidago virgaurea
2014-01-18  Fokus   MFU 351017  Anthoxanthum odoratum
2014-01-24  Test Group  MFU 188772  Lotus corniculatus
```

Comment: what does `show datestyle;` says? According to COPY's doc: _COPY input and output is affected by DateStyle_

Comment: @DanielVérité - and yet, the first example in the manual  is `1999-01-08 - ISO 8601; January 8 in any mode (recommended format)`

Comment: You have some funky characters: `select '2014-01-24'::date` is ok, while the one copied from your `ERROR` line is not. Maybe a BOM? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Pozs, you are todays hero! The file was saved with BOM. When I saved as UTF8 - with no BOM -> all is well with import! Thanks for using your time to look at it :-) As far as "show datestyle" I was using the correct format. It was all about the BOM. Wish I could vote you up!